# Serializing a custom object which has methods. Methods being dropped after serialization - what steps to take?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have created a custom object similar to this simplified example. My implementation gives Playlist more complex methods:

```
function Playlist(id) {
    var _songs = [];

    if(!id)
        id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });

    var playlist = {
        id: id,
        title: "New Playlist",

        clear: function(){
            _songs = [];
            _save();
        },

        songCount: function () {
            return _songs.length;
        },

        getSongs: function () {
            return _songs;
        }
    }

    return playlist;
}
```

Now, I have another object, Playlists, which saves Playlist objects:

```
function playlists(){
    var _playlists = null;
    var _currentPlaylist = null;

    var _save = function () {
        localStorage.setItem('playlists', JSON.stringify(_playlists));
    };

    var _loadPlaylists = function(){
        _playlists = localStorage.getItem('playlists');

        try {
            if (_playlists && _playlists != 'undefined')
                _playlists = JSON.parse(_playlists);
        }
        catch(exception){
            console.error(exception);
        }

        if(!_playlists){
            _playlists = new Array();
            var defaultPlaylist = new Playlist(null, null);

            _playlists.push(defaultPlaylist);
            _save();
        }
    };

    var playlists = {
        count: function(){
            return _playlists.length;
        },

        getPlaylists: function(){
            return _playlists;
        },

        getCurrentPlaylist: function(){
            currentPlaylist = _currentPlaylist;

            if(!currentPlaylist){
                _loadPlaylists();
                currentPlaylist = _playlists[0];
                currentPlaylist.selected = true;
            }

            return currentPlaylist;
        },

        addPlaylist: function(playlistName){
            var playlist = new Playlist(null, playlistName);
            _playlists.push(playlist);
            _save();
        }
    }

    return playlists;
}
```

When I convert a playlist object from JSON to an object using JSON.parse I note that the Playlist object has been stripped of its methods. I believe this is because JSON.stringify does not know how to (or it does not know that it should) convert the object into JSON.

I was wondering what the proper response to this is? Is it possible to tag the methods as serializable? Or is more work required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` saves data properties, not methods.  That's how it works.

If you're expecting it to save your actual javascript code, that is simply not how it's designed.  If you wanted, you could add a data property that was the custom type of the object and when you read back in the object, you could use that to reattach the appropriate methods.  But, that does not happen with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

If you know in advance what type of object you're reading, you can create that type of object and pass it the saved JSON as an initializer.

Comment: Well, how would you achieve what I am attempting, then? Do I give my Playlist object a constructor which accepts JSON and create a new object but set the properties as defined by the old, serialized properties?

Comment: @SeanAnderson - if you know in advance that the object is a particular custom object, then yes, you can manually create that object and pass it the serialized JSON as an initializer.  If you have multiple types of objects and won't know which is which, you may have to save the custom type so you can create the right kind of object when you reconstitute it.  After you read my answer the first time, I had added some more info about this to the answer.

Comment: Sounds good man. Thanks for the information. :) I'll accept in 7.

Comment: Another option, though probably not a good one is before you do your localStorage.set.. operation, you can iterate through each key/value of your object and if a function is found, set the value to string representation of the function (using myFunction.toString). While this isn't an ideal solution (you're saving actual javascript code, it may not work like you expect in all browsers, etc) it is doable. I wouldn't recommend it but a lot of people do a lot of things I wouldn't recommend :P

Comment: @JasonL - that commits your code to local storage, never to be upgraded or bugfixed again.  Not recommended at all (as you said, not a good option).  It's also enormously inefficient, saving a copy of the code for all methods on every object.  Much better to save a property that indicates what kind of object it is and rehook it up to that object's code when the object is recreated.

Comment: @jfriend00 100% agree with your comment. I posted my comment only for completion's sake as sometimes the worst option is the only option :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `stringify` is designed to serialize properties, not function.
I found [this blog post](http://blog.maxaller.name/2011/01/javascript-serialization/) that goes through the process of explaining why this is the case, and finally how to preserve an object's functions through the use of the `__proto__` property. Looks like the only way around it for now.